# What type of for loop is this?

Tags: java, for-loop

Usually I have seen for loops such as:

```java
for(int i; i < 10; i++) {
   // do something
}
```

What type of for loop is this, and how does it work in Java?

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            for (RunnableProducer p : runnableProducers) p.shutdown();
```

Comment: This is just code. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question. Include the actual question in the main body and not the title.

Comment: This is kind a foreach loop which itterate over an array elements. Read about foreach loop

Comment: Some call it an "enhanced for loop", at [Oracle's Java Tutorial for "The for Statement"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) the mention "enhanced for statement"

Answer (score 0):

It is called `for-each` (or `enhanced for loop`) loop. You can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85190/8192914).

**Syntax:**

```java
for(data_type item : collections) {
    ...
}
```

**How it works:**

For each iteration, the loop

1. iterates through each item given in collection or arrays(collection)
2. stores each in a variable (item)
3. and executes the body of the loop.

(read more [here](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/enhanced-for-loop))

Answer (score 0):

This is called a `for-each` loop, a.k.a. "enhanced for loop" in Java. It is, at the basic level, a syntactic sugar for the for loops which iterate over `Iterable` collections. This construct gets rid of the clutter which is present in for loops with Iterables, and therefore, it minimizes possible errors in the code.

As [Java 8 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) instructs:

```java
for (Iterator<TimerTask> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    i.next().cancel();
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```java
for (TimerTask t : c)
        t.cancel();
}
```

It's cleaner and it's prone to less mistakes and errors.